# Lesion load calculation using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have multi-sequence (T1-weighted, T2-weighted) magnetic resonance images with multiple sclerosis (MS) lesion as well as the annotated (label) images. Prior to segmentation I would like to know how I can calculate the **lesion load** using any of the sequence with **MATLAB** or if there is any available tool for this purpose. Will gladly appreciate some help or guide.

The total lesion load (TLL) is estimated from the segmentation of the lesion which in this case is given by a separate labeled mask (label or annotation provided separately)
I have the unlabeled multi-sequence image (let's say T1-weighted) as well as the label for the image. However, I will like to know what is the percentage of lesion is in the unlabeled image using the label (annotation) as reference.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information about the data you have and a definition of "lesion load"

Comment: @Suever I updated my question

Comment: do you have some images to show us what you're trying to do?

Comment: So you... just want to know what percentage of pixels are labelled? Or something else?

Comment: @nkjt Yes. I want to know what percentage of the pixels are labelled which of course is the same as the total amount of lesion

Answer (score 0):

Try the automated lesion identification extension from Mohamed Seghier with the SPM toolbox, more information from http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/ext/

Comment: Thanks! I checked it already. It only identifies the lesion and does not provide the total lesion load (% of lesion)

Comment: It will provide you with a volume of the lession, and with your mask you can calculate the percentage no ? I never heard of this TLL.

Comment: One online paper make use of the tools FreeSurfer with TOADS-CRUISE plugin. The term load is used to define the lesion change in volume ?